# How to secure data transfers between C# and PHP with WebClient?

Tags: c#, php, webclient

I have a C# program (using Unity3D) which I am using to connect to a PHP page on my server.  I'm worried about hackers reading the packets, and about people just being able to send post data to the php page and get a response.  How can I lock the site down so only my app can use it?

Here is my current C# function

```
public static void UploadLevel(int userID, byte[] levelData)
{
    using (var client = new WebClient())
    {
        var values = new NameValueCollection();
        values["uid"] = userID.ToString();
        values["leveldata"] = System.Convert.ToBase64String(levelData);

        var response = client.UploadValues("http://example.com/code/uploadlevel.php", values);

        var responseString = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(response);
    }
}
```

And here is the start of the php page

```
<?php
if (!isset($_POST['uid']))
{
    echo "ERROR: 100";
    exit;
}
if (!is_numeric($_POST['uid']))
{
    echo "ERROR: 200";
    exit;
}

if (!isset($_POST['leveldata']))
{
    echo "ERROR: 300";
    exit;
}
?>
```

Comment: `https://` to achieve transport-layer security for the packets, then some (by an attacker) unforgable UID / validation string for the actual data sent. The latter is definetly more difficult to do.

Comment: It is fundamentally impossible to distingiush between your app and an attacker who can decompile your app.

Comment: The identity of your app can always be spoofed, regardless of what method you choose to try to identify your app. The best way to secure against packet sniffing is to use SSL to secure the transport.

Comment: yes SSL as stated above, but you should also obscure the data being sent, ie don't use `uid` as the key value of your post make it gibberish, and if that value isn't present then you don't respond.